# Troubleshooting 1 modem 1 switch 2 wifi routers (one-2.4ghz & one-5ghz)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I would like to know why I have internet access with 1 wifi router and local access only with the 2nd wifi router.

I am also confused by IPv4 address while connected to the Dlink router. During the Dlink setup, I set its local address to 192.168.8.1. However, ipconfig says it is 169.254.109.

Why am I doing this? I want to extend the range. The Netgear router only uses the 2.4ghz band. The Dlink only uses the 5ghz band.

Please ask me to provide any additional information.

I am attached to the devices as follows

- Cable modem ---- Gigabit switch
- Gigabit switch ---- Netgear WAN (internet access)
- Gigabit switch ---- Dlink WAN (local access)

Netgear ipconfig:

- Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
- Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
- Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d18:4bc1:f7ae:6d49%4
- IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.7
- Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1

Dlink ipconfig:

- Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
- Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
- Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d18:4bc1:f7ae:6d49%4
- Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.109.73
- Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
- Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cause doesn't seem to be clear, but I do see a few things:

- Your subnet masks are inconsistent. Both must be 255.255.255.0.
- Your default gateway for the Dlink router was never configured. I believe you need to set your router's IP to 10.0.0.2?
- If nothing works, your cable modem is probably in bridge mode. This means that your modem will give a WAN IP address usually to only one client connected to it (your Netgear router). You need to change that to router mode or "normal" mode so that your modem may assign IP addresses to each router as if they were clients.

Comment: So um, which one of the three fixed it?

Comment: The modem would only register internet to 1 router. For the Dlink router 1) I turned DHCP off 2) made sure the subnet mask was 255.255.255.0 3) Put the router up to 10.0.0.2 4) connected the Dlink's LAN port to the Netgear's LAN port. I had hoped to not cascade the two routers but what I learned was that a router must be in cascade to avoid multiple devices assigning local ips. The best strategy is to avoid chaining by using a switch if I expand to more routers.

Comment: Yep, you got it. Your next task is to get the two routers to broadcast to the same SSID but different channels.